# Replace text in file with Python

Tags: python, file, text, replace

I'm trying to replace some text in a file with a value. Everything works fine but when I look at the file after its completed there is a new (blank) line after each line in the file. Is there something I can do to prevent this from happening.

Here is the code as I have it:

```
  import fileinput
    for line in fileinput.FileInput("testfile.txt",inplace=1):
       line = line.replace("newhost",host)
       print line
```

Thank you,
Aaron

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each `line` is read from the file with its ending newline, and the print adds one of its own.

You can:

```
print line,
```

Which won't add a newline after the line.

Comment: So it turns out I'm running into an issue. For some reason when I do this text replace something else is happening to the file. I use a program called TextWrangler for text editing and when I try to open the file it tells me "An unexpected I/O error occurred (MacOS Error code: -36). Before this "find and replace" it opens fine. Any idea what could be causing something like this?

Comment: I did just see that when i try to view the original file from the terminal it asks if i want to view because it is a binary file. Maybe this is the problem?

Comment: @Aaron: Maybe you have a newline issue between two OSes? I suggest you define the problem exactly and open a new question. Try to include as much information as possible

Answer (score 2):

The `print line` automatically adds a newline. You'd best do a `sys.stdout.write(line)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

[`print`](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-print-statement) adds a new-line character:

> A '\n' character is written at the end, unless the print statement ends with a comma. This is the only action if the statement contains just the keyword print.